# tinymce paste HTML tag <poll poll-id="'POLL ID'">

Tags: javascript, html, css, tinymce

when I try to paste in the code editor
He cut my tag. it does not allow it ..
I do not understand, I tried everything.

somebody can help me..

```
<div class="polls form" id="poll-container" ng-app="poll">
<poll poll-id="'POLL ID'"></poll>
</div>
```

give me >

```
<div class="polls form" id="poll-container" ng-app="poll"></div>




extended_valid_elements: 'poll[poll-id|defer|language|src|type]',
custom_elements: "*[*]",
valid_elements: "*[*]",
```

or

```
extended_valid_elements: "*[*]",
custom_elements: "*[*]",
valid_elements: "*[*]",
```

lots of other thing;...
nothing works: (

Comment: can you create a tinymce fiddle for this?

Comment: yes thanks you,     http://fiddle.tinymce.com/Gfeaab/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tinymce somehow has a problem with the tag being empty.
Try to put a character inside it and it won't get stripped out.

Comment: I do not thought about that, thanks you :)  <div class="polls form" id="poll-container" ng-app="poll"><poll poll-id="'POLL ID'">&nbsp;</poll></div>

Comment: glad to have been able to help